# mdframed rounded corner on left side only

Tags: mdframed

I would like to get the roundered corners on only `leftside` instead of `top, bottom, right, bottom`. How to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{
roundcorner=20pt
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use tcolorbox instead of mdframed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{arc=20pt,
        sharp corners=east}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would use `tcolorbox` too, but this would illustrate `mdframed` way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{
hidealllines=true,
singleextra={\draw[line width=1pt,rounded corners=20pt](O-|P) -| (O|-P) -- (P);
\draw[line width=1pt] (P) -- (O-|P);
},
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]